# How to get all records using map

Tags: java

I m trying to display all records but it shows only last record because its value is overwritten every time.How to solve this issue ?

```
File fXmlFile = new File("d:/formdata.xml");

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("record");
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    map.put("Item No", eElement.getElementsByTagName("item_no").item(0).getTextContent());
                    map.put("Description", eElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent());
                    map.put("price", eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent());
                    map.put("base qty", eElement.getElementsByTagName("base_qty").item(0).getTextContent());
                    map.put("Var qty", eElement.getElementsByTagName("var_qty").item(0).getTextContent());



                    generateCsvFile("E:\\testCSV.csv", map);
                }
              }
```

When call generateCSVfile()

```
private static void generateCsvFile(String sFilename, Map<String, Object> test) {
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFilename,true);

        Iterator iterator = test.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
            System.out.println("key: " + mapEntry.getKey() + ", value:" + mapEntry.getValue());
            writer.append(mapEntry.getKey() + " = " + mapEntry.getValue());
            writer.append(",");
            iterator.remove();
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
```

How can we store all value in Map?

Answer (score 0):

```
map.put("Item No", eElement.getElementsByTagName("item_no").item(0).getTextContent());
map.put("Description", eElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent());
map.put("price", eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent());
map.put("base qty", eElement.getElementsByTagName("base_qty").item(0).getTextContent());
map.put("Var qty", eElement.getElementsByTagName("var_qty").item(0).getTextContent());
```

You are keeping keys same everytime, as "Item No" etc, so everytime, values will be overwritten. Put map into a list and finally send that list to your method.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Can please tell me what can i use instead of map?

Comment: Take a look at guava's [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I see the `Map` key represents column when value - data. So you put all *rows* into the same key.

I suggest you to create basic class `Line` and use `List<Line>`.

```
class Line{
 private String ItemNo = "";
 private String Description = "";
 private String price = "";
 private String baseQty = "";
 private String VarQty = "";

 //getters/setters
}

 ...

 List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
```

Instead:

```
map.put("Item No", eElement.getElementsByTagName("item_no").item(0).getTextContent());
map.put("Description", eElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent());
map.put("price", eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent());
map.put("base qty", eElement.getElementsByTagName("base_qty").item(0).getTextContent());
map.put("Var qty", eElement.getElementsByTagName("var_qty").item(0).getTextContent());
```

we will write:

```
 Line line = new Line();
 line.setItemNo(eElement.getElementsByTagName("item_no").item(0).getTextContent());
 line.setDescription(eElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent());
 ...
 lines.add(line);
```

In `generateCsvFile` method we just write something like:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFilename,true);
writer.append("Item No, Description, .....");// add header
```

and run in loop over list to add rows like:

```
for(Line line : lines){ 
writer.append(line.getItemNo()).append(","); 
writer.append(line.getDescription()).append(","); 
...
writer.append("\n");
}
```

Comment: see my example where i define class Line

Comment: why are you define another class Line? sorry but i m not getting u

Comment: Because its easy to manage. You know that each line in CSV represents class Line

Comment: Sorry, its out of question scope

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to pass a List of values to generateCSVfile().  Right now, you are passing only one row.

One way to do it is, put all your maps in a list and pass the list to generateCSVfile.

But I would recommend you create a new class to hold the values.  Say a class called `Row` which will hold your values, and pass List to generateCSVfile()

Answer (score 0):

You need List of Map objects

```
List< Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
     Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
     if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
           Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
           map.put("Item No", eElement.getElementsByTagName("item_no").item(0).getTextContent());
           map.put("Description", eElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent());
           map.put("price", eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent());
           map.put("base qty", eElement.getElementsByTagName("base_qty").item(0).getTextContent());
           map.put("Var qty", eElement.getElementsByTagName("var_qty").item(0).getTextContent());
           list.add(map);               
      }
}

generateCsvFile("E:\\testCSV.csv", list );
```

now your generateCSVfile() method looks like

```
private static void generateCsvFile(String sFilename, List< Map<String, String>>  test) {
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFilename,true);
            for (Map<String, String> map : test) {          

            Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String,String> mapEntry = (Map.Entry<String,String>) iterator.next();
                System.out.println("key: " + mapEntry.getKey() + ", value:" + mapEntry.getValue());
                writer.append(mapEntry.getKey());
                writer.append(mapEntry.getValue());
                writer.append(",");
                iterator.remove();
            }
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
```

Comment: @Aanshi make sure you are calling generateCsvFile("E:\\testCSV.csv", list ); outside the for loop.

Comment: Now its working but its shows value in key value pair.So i right this  writer.append mapEntry.getValue()); but shows error

Comment: @Aanshi change your  Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next(); to  Map.Entry<String,Object> mapEntry = (Map.Entry<String,Object>) iterator.next(); inside the while loop

Comment: now its generate output file,but in file its shows "price = 10" in this format

Comment: @Aanshi I am not sure how to write to csv file with formatting.